# classification threshold in RandomForest-sklearn

Tags: classification, random-forest, precision-recall, unbalanced-classes

1) How can I change classification threshold (i think it is 0.5 by default) in RandomForest in sklearn?

2) how can I under-sample in sklearn?

3) I have the following result from RandomForest classifier:
[[1635 1297]
 [ 520 3624]]

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

class 0       0.76      0.56      0.64      2932
class 1       0.74      0.87      0.80      4144
```

avg / total       0.75      0.74      0.73      7076

first, data is unbalanced (30% from class-0 and 70% from class-1). So, I think the classifier is more likely to be biased for class-1 meaning move some from class-0 to class-1 (there are 1297 missclassification for class-0 but 520 missclassification for class-1). How can I fix this? if downsampling can help? or changing classification threshold?

Update: class-0 has 40% of population while class-1 is 60%. However, drift from class-0 to class-1 (1297) is high while I want this becomes low.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could indeed wrap you random forest in a class that a `predict` methods that calls the `predict_proba` method of the internal random forest and output class 1 only if it's higher than a custom threshold.

Alternatively you can bias the training algorithm by passing a higher `sample_weight` for samples from the minority class.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about increasing weight for minor class. However, I can not see anything in RandomForest classifier (there is in SGDclassifier)

Comment: The fit method accept a `sample_weight` param (one weight per parameter) that is very flexible and makes it possible to simulate `class_weight` (one weight per target class).

Comment: Thanks. when I use clf = clf.fit(X, Y, sample_weight=preprocessing.balance_weights(y) it gives me ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes. y is binary 0/1

Comment: What is the shape of `y`? Why do you have different `Y` and `y`?